# Enums or sealed classes with strings

Tags: android, kotlin, enums

Can I create an `enum` or a `sealed class` in `Kotlin` that contain string resources?

For instance, I have this class:

```
private enum class Item(
    val id: Int,
    @DrawableRes val imageRes: Int,
    val title: String
) {
    PURSE(1, R.drawable.ic_card, "My balance"),
    MESSAGES(2, R.drawable.ic_bell, "Messages")
}
```

If I add a field `val resources: Resources` in the constructor, I cannot set a parameter `resources`, so cannot use string resources from `strings.xml`. In this case I cannot use localization for `enum`s.

Comment: why not pass the @StringRes like you do with the image?

Comment: @TimCastelijns, please, add your answer, I will accept.

Comment: I'm not sure how it is the answer though. Surely you thought of this solution already

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need a Resources instance. You can use a string resource, like you did for the drawable:

```
private enum class Item(
    val id: Int,
    @DrawableRes val imageRes: Int,
    @StringRes val title: Int
)
```